# how to access private class variable from a different class in typescript (react-redux application)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that has a `cachedData` variable. Its a private variable.
This variable (cachedData) gets updated from a different class. I can not create a static method as I can not do `this.cachedData` inside static method. But I also want the other classes to update this variable. How do I achieve this?

```
      class myClass implements X{

      private cachedData:Array<entity>;

      cacheResponseData = ( val ):void => {
       this.cachedData = val;
       }

       clearSourceData = ():void => {
         this.cachedData = null;
       }

      }


      class OtherClass extends Y {

        constructor(
        dataProvider: QueryablePagedDataProvider<ReportingEntity>,
       ){
        super(dataProvider, DataStoreMode.SINGLE_PAGE);
       }

       someMethod()
       {
        // I need to update the cachedData in this method from myClass

       }


       }
```

Comment: "*I have a class that has a cachedData variable*" - no. Not the class has the variable, but its instances will. If you want to change the value (i.e. call `cacheResponseData()`), on *which instance* do you want to do it? Your other class will need to know.

Comment: in the someMethod of OtherClass I want to update cachedData from myClass. How to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you said that already. And I explained that it doesn't make sense. `myClass` has no `cachedData`, only a `new myClass()` instance has.